# i'm trying to install odoo 12 on ubuntu 18.04 and i'm facing issue about npm so i want to remove node completley , but i'm facing errors

Tags: package-management, dependencies, nodejs, npm, odoo

i'm facing issues about npm while installing odoo12
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed"

so i'm trying to remove existing node with all component to fix this issue
i've comlpete remove node from my machine with command
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
and yet when i type 
node -v 
reply : v8.11.3
i'm using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

I have a better solution that can be helpful to others.
I have just modified the existing script and it works like a charm.

I modified [Yenthe Van Ginneken script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/12.0/odoo_install.sh)

- Change requirements libraries installation process.
- Add new python libraries and modified specific versions of python libraries.
- Change the npm install process.

  ```
   #!/bin/bash
    ################################################################################
    # Script for installing Odoo on Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04, 16.04 and 18.04 (could be used for other version too)
    # Author: Yenthe Van Ginneken
    # Modified by: Shahid Raza
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # This script will install Odoo on your Ubuntu 16.04 server. It can install multiple Odoo instances
    # in one Ubuntu because of the different xmlrpc_ports
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Make a new file:
    # sudo nano odoo-install.sh
    # Place this content in it and then make the file executable:
    # sudo chmod +x odoo-install.sh
    # Execute the script to install Odoo:
    # ./odoo-install
    ################################################################################

    #OE_USER is your system user change name according your system
    OE_USER="odoo"
    OE_HOME="/$OE_USER"
    OE_HOME_EXT="/$OE_USER/${OE_USER}-server"
    # The default port where this Odoo instance will run under (provided you use the command -c in the terminal)
    # Set to true if you want to install it, false if you don't need it or have it already installed.
    INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF="True"
    # Set the default Odoo port (you still have to use -c /etc/odoo-server.conf for example to use this.)
    OE_PORT="8069"
    # Choose the Odoo version which you want to install. For example: 12.0, 11.0, 10.0 or saas-18. When using 'master' the master version will be installed.
    # IMPORTANT! This script contains extra libraries that are specifically needed for Odoo 12.0
    OE_VERSION="12.0"
    # Set this to True if you want to install the Odoo enterprise version!
    IS_ENTERPRISE="False"
    # set the superadmin password
    OE_SUPERADMIN="admin"
    OE_CONFIG="${OE_USER}-server"

    ##
    ###  WKHTMLTOPDF download links
    ## === Ubuntu Trusty x64 & x32 === (for other distributions please replace these two links,
    ## in order to have correct version of wkhtmltopdf installed, for a danger note refer to 
    ## https://github.com/odoo/odoo/wiki/Wkhtmltopdf ):
    WKHTMLTOX_X64=https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_amd64.deb
    WKHTMLTOX_X32=https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_i386.deb

    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Update Server
    #--------------------------------------------------
    echo -e "\n---- Update Server ----"

    # add-apt-repository can install add-apt-repository Ubuntu 18.x
    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
    # universe package is for Ubuntu 18.x
    sudo add-apt-repository universe
    # libpng12-0 dependency for wkhtmltopdf
    sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/ xenial main"
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade -y

    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Install PostgreSQL Server
    #--------------------------------------------------
    echo -e "\n---- Install PostgreSQL Server ----"
    sudo apt-get install postgresql -y

    echo -e "\n---- Creating the ODOO PostgreSQL User  ----"
    sudo su - postgres -c "createuser -s $OE_USER" 2> /dev/null || true

    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Install Dependencies
    #--------------------------------------------------
    echo -e "\n--- Installing Python 3 + pip3 --"
    sudo apt-get install git python3 python3-pip build-essential wget python3-dev python3-venv python3-wheel libxslt-dev libzip-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev python3-setuptools node-less libpng12-0 gdebi -y

    echo -e "\n---- Install python packages/requirements ----"
    sudo pip3 install Babel
    sudo pip3 install chardet
    sudo pip3 install decorator
    sudo pip3 install docutils
    sudo pip3 install ebaysdk
    sudo pip3 install feedparser
    sudo pip3 install gevent
    sudo pip3 install greenlet
    sudo pip3 install html2text
    sudo pip3 install Jinja2
    sudo pip3 install lxml
    sudo pip3 install Mako
    sudo pip3 install MarkupSafe
    sudo pip3 install mock
    sudo pip3 install num2words
    sudo pip3 install ofxparse
    sudo pip3 install passlib
    sudo pip3 install Pillow
    sudo pip3 install psutil
    sudo pip3 install psycopg2-binary
    sudo pip3 install pydot
    sudo pip3 install pyldap
    sudo pip3 install pyparsing
    sudo pip3 install PyPDF2
    sudo pip3 install pyserial
    sudo pip3 install python-dateutil
    sudo pip3 install pytz
    sudo pip3 install pyusb
    sudo pip3 install qrcode
    sudo pip3 install reportlab
    sudo pip3 install requests
    sudo pip3 install suds-jurko
    sudo pip3 install vatnumber
    sudo pip3 install vobject
    sudo pip3 install Werkzeug==0.11.15
    sudo pip3 install XlsxWriter
    sudo pip3 install xlwt
    sudo pip3 install xlrd
    sudo pip3 install pypiwin32
    sudo pip3 install libsass==0.12.3

    echo -e "\n---- Installing nodeJS NPM and rtlcss for LTR support ----"
    sudo apt-get install -y npm
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
    sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
    sudo apt-get install -y node-less

    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Install Wkhtmltopdf if needed
    #--------------------------------------------------
    if [ $INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF = "True" ]; then
      echo -e "\n---- Install wkhtml and place shortcuts on correct place for ODOO 12 ----"
      #pick up correct one from x64 & x32 versions:
      if [ "`getconf LONG_BIT`" == "64" ];then
          _url=$WKHTMLTOX_X64
      else
          _url=$WKHTMLTOX_X32
      fi
      sudo wget $_url
      sudo gdebi --n `basename $_url`
      sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
      sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
    else
      echo "Wkhtmltopdf isn't installed due to the choice of the user!"
    fi

    echo -e "\n---- Create ODOO system user ----"
    sudo adduser --system --quiet --shell=/bin/bash --home=$OE_HOME --gecos 'ODOO' --group $OE_USER
    #The user should also be added to the sudo'ers group.
    sudo adduser $OE_USER sudo

    echo -e "\n---- Create Log directory ----"
    sudo mkdir /var/log/$OE_USER
    sudo chown $OE_USER:$OE_USER /var/log/$OE_USER

    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Install ODOO
    #--------------------------------------------------
    echo -e "\n==== Installing ODOO Server ===="
    sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch $OE_VERSION https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo $OE_HOME_EXT/

    if [ $IS_ENTERPRISE = "True" ]; then
        # Odoo Enterprise install!
        echo -e "\n--- Create symlink for node"
        sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
        sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/enterprise"
        sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/enterprise/addons"

        GITHUB_RESPONSE=$(sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch $OE_VERSION https://www.github.com/odoo/enterprise "$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons" 2>&1)
        while [[ $GITHUB_RESPONSE == *"Authentication"* ]]; do
            echo "------------------------WARNING------------------------------"
            echo "Your authentication with Github has failed! Please try again."
            printf "In order to clone and install the Odoo enterprise version you \nneed to be an offical Odoo partner and you need access to\nhttp://github.com/odoo/enterprise.\n"
            echo "TIP: Press ctrl+c to stop this script."
            echo "-------------------------------------------------------------"
            echo " "
            GITHUB_RESPONSE=$(sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch $OE_VERSION https://www.github.com/odoo/enterprise "$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons" 2>&1)
        done

        echo -e "\n---- Added Enterprise code under $OE_HOME/enterprise/addons ----"
        echo -e "\n---- Installing Enterprise specific libraries ----"
        sudo pip3 install num2words ofxparse
        sudo npm install -g less
        sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
    fi

    echo -e "\n---- Create custom module directory ----"
    sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/custom"
    sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/custom/addons"

    echo -e "\n---- Setting permissions on home folder ----"
    sudo chown -R $OE_USER:$OE_USER $OE_HOME/*

    echo -e "* Create server config file"

    sudo touch /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
    echo -e "* Creating server config file"
    sudo su root -c "printf '[options] \n; This is the password that allows database operations:\n' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
    sudo su root -c "printf 'admin_passwd = ${OE_SUPERADMIN}\n' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
    sudo su root -c "printf 'xmlrpc_port = ${OE_PORT}\n' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
    sudo su root -c "printf 'logfile = /var/log/${OE_USER}/${OE_CONFIG}.log\n' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
    if [ $IS_ENTERPRISE = "True" ]; then
        sudo su root -c "printf 'addons_path=${OE_HOME}/enterprise/addons,${OE_HOME_EXT}/addons\n' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
    else
        sudo su root -c "printf 'addons_path=${OE_HOME_EXT}/addons,${OE_HOME}/custom/addons\n' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
    fi
    sudo chown $OE_USER:$OE_USER /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
    sudo chmod 640 /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf

    echo -e "* Create startup file"
    sudo su root -c "echo '#!/bin/sh' >> $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh"
    sudo su root -c "echo 'sudo -u $OE_USER $OE_HOME_EXT/openerp-server --config=/etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf' >> $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh"
    sudo chmod 755 $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh

    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Adding ODOO as a deamon (initscript)
    #--------------------------------------------------

    echo -e "* Create init file"
    cat <<EOF > ~/$OE_CONFIG
    #!/bin/sh
    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides: $OE_CONFIG
    # Required-Start: \$remote_fs \$syslog
    # Required-Stop: \$remote_fs \$syslog
    # Should-Start: \$network
    # Should-Stop: \$network
    # Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop: 0 1 6
    # Short-Description: Enterprise Business Applications
    # Description: ODOO Business Applications
    ### END INIT INFO
    PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
    DAEMON=$OE_HOME_EXT/odoo-bin
    NAME=$OE_CONFIG
    DESC=$OE_CONFIG
    # Specify the user name (Default: odoo).
    USER=$OE_USER
    # Specify an alternate config file (Default: /etc/openerp-server.conf).
    CONFIGFILE="/etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
    # pidfile
    PIDFILE=/var/run/\${NAME}.pid
    # Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.
    DAEMON_OPTS="-c \$CONFIGFILE"
    [ -x \$DAEMON ] || exit 0
    [ -f \$CONFIGFILE ] || exit 0
    checkpid() {
    [ -f \$PIDFILE ] || return 1
    pid=\`cat \$PIDFILE\`
    [ -d /proc/\$pid ] && return 0
    return 1
    }
    case "\${1}" in
    start)
    echo -n "Starting \${DESC}: "
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
    --chuid \$USER --background --make-pidfile \
    --exec \$DAEMON -- \$DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "\${NAME}."
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Stopping \${DESC}: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
    --oknodo
    echo "\${NAME}."
    ;;
    restart|force-reload)
    echo -n "Restarting \${DESC}: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
    --oknodo
    sleep 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
    --chuid \$USER --background --make-pidfile \
    --exec \$DAEMON -- \$DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "\${NAME}."
    ;;
    *)
    N=/etc/init.d/\$NAME
    echo "Usage: \$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
    esac
    exit 0
    EOF

    echo -e "* Security Init File"
    sudo mv ~/$OE_CONFIG /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
    sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
    sudo chown root: /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG

    echo -e "* Start ODOO on Startup"
    sudo update-rc.d $OE_CONFIG defaults

    echo -e "* Starting Odoo Service"
    sudo su root -c "/etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG start"
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Done! The Odoo server is up and running. Specifications:"
    echo "Port: $OE_PORT"
    echo "User service: $OE_USER"
    echo "User PostgreSQL: $OE_USER"
    echo "Code location: $OE_USER"
    echo "Addons folder: $OE_USER/$OE_CONFIG/addons/"
    echo "Start Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG start"
    echo "Stop Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG stop"
    echo "Restart Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG restart"
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Installing `nodejs` will install `npm`. So just remove `nodejs` then reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs node npm
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

You can also fix your broken package with this,

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After once try again to hit command it will be solved your issue.